# Eliminating gap between vertical borders of table <td>s

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a resume that I'm trying to translate from MS Word into HTML and CSS for easier maintenance and sharing. I like the style of the resume, and would prefer to keep it. It has a left column, with titles like "Education", "Experience", etc. in bold, and right-aligned against a vertical separator.

In Word this is achieved by a table, with the style of the central border set to solid, and the other borders set to blank. This allows the section titles to be vertically aligned with the associated content.

I tried to simply duplicate this technique, but in Firefox and Chrome, if I set a column of tds' border-right attributes to solid, there are gaps at the vertical divisions of the table. This sort of ruins the effect.

I thought of using two divs, one with the headings and one with the content, but other than hard-coding pixel heights (which has its own obvious sets of problems), I can't figure out how to keep them vertically in-sync.

Is there a way to do this without losing the ability to keep the titles and their associated content  vertically aligned?

The table code looks something like

```
<table>
<tr><td style="border-right:1px solid black;">Education</td><td> [Name of School, etc.]</td></tr>
<tr><td style="border-right:1px solid black;">Experience</td><td>[Work experience]</td></tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```

`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “gaps at the vertical divisions of the table”, and please post some code.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or whatever so that we can see exactly what you want?

Comment: Could you please share some code of what you've tried so far, and perhaps an image of what you are trying to accomplish. That would be of much help. You can share the code with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for instance.

Comment: You should play with \http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-collapse

Comment: You probably want to use a CSS Reset before you start; this will zero out all the padding and margins and make the site web browser independent. See http://sixrevisions.com/css/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-resets/

Comment: convert `word` file into a `pdf` & host it using `embed` or `object` tags!

Comment: @Truth: I tried, but I'm unfortunately too new here to post images.

Comment: @Dave, Part of the point is that I keep losing my .docx files and being forced to recreate them from an impenetrable pdf. Also, it's likely that my audience won't have a pdf plugin in their browser.

Comment: then I would say what Truth has told. upload a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: @Dave: As this is my first question here, I don't have enough karma to post images.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

It would eliminate the gaps and allow table borders.

Answer (score 10):

On the table, set the `border-spacing: 0;` which removes spaces between borders of the child `TD` elements.

Comment: lifesaver!, sneaky table styles

Comment: Using `border-collapse: collapse;` left small gaps in my table, but this eliminated them. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Dispensing with the table is the better idea.
You can turn the headings into `<h2>` elements (or whatever level of `<h>` is appropriate) and have it float left and give the text a wide enough left margin.

Something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFGmC/), or is this not what you want?

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Having been told The Right Thing, it always seems so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Why make your life complicated when you can do the following:

convert `word` file into a `pdf` & host it using HTML `embed` or `object` tags!

**edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/WzGeX/2/

Comment: Part of the point is that I keep losing my .docx files and being forced to recreate them from an impenetrable pdf. Also, it's likely that my audience won't have a pdf plugin in their browser. I'd much rather just have a single, vim-editable file that I can then quickly push to a server, rather than going through that whole process every time I notice a typo or gain experience.

Comment: See this example: you mean to say you want something this?http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/WzGeX/2/

Comment: Actually, http://jsfiddle.net/kFGmC/ is almost exactly what I was hoping for. I just didn't think to treat `<hx>` tags as the block elements that they are.